# importing database table to algolia

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent, algolia

At algolia website i found this code but it is not adding any index at the algolia website. i am working fine with a search for an index that algolia provides ""getstarted_actors"". but i want to import my own database data  to be created as index. please help

The following code adds search capabilities to your Contact model creating a Contact index:

```
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use AlgoliaSearch\Laravel\AlgoliaEloquentTrait;

    class Contact extends Model 
    { use AlgoliaEloquentTrait;
     }
```

Comment: Hi Ahmed do you have any attribute in your model? Did you save your model before checking if it was in Algolia?

Comment: Actually sir i don't know how to initially export your database data to algolia. something has to be done for initial import. The above thing is not enough

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to initially import your data into Algolia you need to use the [`reindex`](https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-laravel#reindexing) added by the AlgoliaEloquentTrait on your model. This is because the `autoindex` feature is only triggered after you make changes, so the initial import has to be done manually.

This will look like:

```
YourModel::reindex();
```

Comment: i should add this to my model for initial import??

Comment: You should execute that method on your model yes.